SignalR server ngrok and ııs connection problem
I'm trying to connect my SignalR server to different devices using ngrok and IIS so that they can communicate with my hub while my server is running. I'm attempting to link my server to the domain I obtained from ngrok. I have conveyed the file path to the relevant site in IIS. However, I must be making a mistake somewhere because the site isn't showing up. Since the server also has a frontend, it should normally redirect me to a single-page web application where I can perform operations after installation, but it's not working. Either I couldn't link the site to the domain, or I couldn't upload the files to the site. Is there anyone who has knowledge about this issue?enter image description here[enter image description here](https://i.sstatic.net/82uoWIFT.jpg)


Right-Click the signalR site and click Explore, make sure the project_name.dll in this folder.



Edit permission like this link, and add IIS_IUSRS and IUSR.

